# SSIS Script Transformation Error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, ssis-2012, script-component

SSIS Script transformation is giving an error:
The binary code for the script is not found.

Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it

builds successfully"

I have opened the editor and rebuild ,but shows the  error

Error   3   'Input0Buffer' does not contain a definition for 'Column1' and no extension method 'Column1' accepting a first argument of type 'Input0Buffer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make your input column available inside the script component (see the picture, in my case I made all columns available).

[image: available input column from data stream]

Comment: All the required input column already selected.When selected and deselected the column its ok.There are 400 columns showing the same error .Is there any property to set to make it correct!?

Comment: script main property build action set to none

Comment: According this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c9fe8092-f733-47a0-99ef-d86342239f81/input0buffer-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-column-in-script-task-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices you have problem with bad name for one of your input column. Be careful with the name because SSIS variables are CASE SENSITIVE. So that means "SegmentCode" is something different than "Segmentcode".

Comment: The thing is         string RecordAsString ;
                           System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();                   all the columns sb.Append(Row.Column1) ..... sb.Append(Row.Column n)  says the input buffer doews not contain a definition of the column.But,if i retype        sb.Append(Row.Column1) then that is fine

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a data column called `Column1` in the data source that is feeding into your scripting component.

Check your data source  / query that is coming into the scripting component and either remove that `column1` field, or uncheck it so it doesn't feed into the scripting component.